# Linq: Checking if string column has a value (ie. is not null or empty)

Tags: vb.net, linq, dynamics-crm-2011

Not sure if this is the best way to achieve this in Linq.

I'm trying to select Contact records in CRM 2011 where the EMailAddress1 contains a value. The following WHERE clauses I tried both caused exceptions:

```
Where c.EMailAddress1 > ""

Where Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.EMailAddress1)
```

So I ended up trying this, which seems to work ok:

```
Where Not c.EMailAddress1.Equals(String.Empty) _
And Not c.EMailAddress1.Equals(Nothing)
```

But I'm just not certain if this is the most efficient method.. it doesn't seem very elegant. Is there a neater way of checking if a string column has a value?

Comment: when you use String.IsNullOrEmpty, what is the exception that you are getting?

Comment: what data type is EMailAddress1?

Comment: @ForteL. the exception is "Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method.". Data type is String.

Comment: I mean the data type in the database

Comment: Ah, not sure, it's a remote installation of CRM 2011, but I assume it would be nvarchar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328328.aspx#limitations) Linq to CRM is really limited. That's why you can't use String.IsNullOrEmpty.

However, you should try to do this :

```
Where c.EMailAddress1 IsNot Nothing
```

When a field is empty, it's set to null in the database (never empty). This line should then be enough for your case.

Regards,

Kévin

Comment: Thanks for the link. I also want to check for "" (blank string, not null) though, so Nothing by itself won't be enough. Seems like it has to be done using 2 conditions, fair enough.

Comment: Actually, if the user let blank the field, it will be NULL. You will never found any result if you look after blank string by using linq. So "IsNot Nothing" should be enough.

Comment: Is that just a Linq behaviour? Many database designs avoid nullable columns. Not sure about CRM 2011 in this case. But assuming a column in the db is VarChar NOT NULL, would linq then treat null and "" (empty) differently?

Comment: This is a CRM 2011 behaviour. If a field is empty (= empty string), CRM will set it to NULL in the database. Within the CRM database, all columns are nullable, the requirement is managed by the CRM program itself, not the DB. That's why you don't have to treat empty strings. They doesn't exist within CRM.

Answer (score 2):

just do :

```
Where c.EmailAddress <> ""
```

Comment: That also raises the exception: "Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method."

Comment: Where(Function(s) s.EmailAddress <> "") = works! Null and Empty strings are not Selected.